# How to achieve block ui kind of behaviour in angular 2

Tags: angular

How is it possible to achieve block ui(http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos) kind of blocking  user interaction in angular 2 ? Could someone please help.

Answer (score 5):

spinner.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'spinner',
    styleUrls: ['spinner.css'],
    //I'm using in modal-backdrop classes from bootstrap
    template:
    `<div class="in modal-backdrop spinner-overlay"></div>
     <div class="spinner-message-container" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="spinner-message" [ngClass]="spinnerMessageClass">{{ state.message }}</div>
    </div>`
})
export class SpinnerComponent {
    state = {
        message: 'Please wait...'
    };
}
```

spinner.css

```
.spinner-overlay {
  background-color: white;
  cursor: wait;
}

.spinner-message-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10001;
  cursor: wait;
}

.spinner-message {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

spinner.service.ts

```
import {Injectable, DynamicComponentLoader, ApplicationRef, ElementRef, ComponentRef} from 'angular2/core';

import {SpinnerComponent} from './spinner.component';

@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService {
    spinnerComp: ComponentRef;
    constructor(private componentLoader: DynamicComponentLoader, private appRef: ApplicationRef) { }

    public start() {
        let elementRef: ElementRef = this.appRef['_rootComponents'][0].location;

        return this.startInside(elementRef, null);
    }

    public startInside(elementRef: ElementRef, anchorName: string) {

        let spinnerRef = (!anchorName) ?
                            this.componentLoader.loadNextToLocation(SpinnerComponent, elementRef) :
                            this.componentLoader.loadIntoLocation(SpinnerComponent, elementRef, anchorName);

        spinnerRef.then((compRef:ComponentRef) => {
            this.spinnerComp = compRef;
        });
    }

    public stop() {
        if (this.spinnerComp) {
            this.spinnerComp.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Inject spinner service to your component. call start and stop to display and hide.

**update**: demo plnkr link: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y2ocRpbi2ORjbULrguDg

disclaimer: I have used one existing angular2 library  as reference to create above code in my project.  I'm searching for that library and will update the same here when I find it.

Comment: Could you please post an example of how you're using this in a page template?  Thanks.

Comment: added plnkr link. @deepugn plz mark my post as answered, if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Very good but broke on > ["beta.16"](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta16-2016-04-26). Any fix for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Angular 2 blockui with spinner (can be customized as per your needs)

Please find below code which works perfectly with angular 2

**spinner.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-spinner',
    //templateUrl: 'app/components/spinner/spinner.html'
    template: `
    <div [hidden]="!isDelayedRunning" class="spinnercontainer">
        <div class="spinner">  
            <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
            <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    `,
    styleUrls:['app/spinner.component.css']
})
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnDestroy {  
    private currentTimeout: any;
    private isDelayedRunning: boolean = false;

    @Input()
    public delay: number = 300;

    @Input()
    public set isRunning(value: boolean) {
        if (!value) {
            this.cancelTimeout();
            this.isDelayedRunning = false;
        }

        if (this.currentTimeout) {
            return;
        }

        this.currentTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.isDelayedRunning = value;
            this.cancelTimeout();
        }, this.delay);
    }

    private cancelTimeout(): void {
        clearTimeout(this.currentTimeout);
        this.currentTimeout = undefined;
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): any {
        this.cancelTimeout();
    }
}
```

**spinner.component.css**

```
.spinnercontainer{
    background-color: transparant;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 20000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    display:block;
    z-index: 20001;
}
.spinner {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.double-bounce1, .double-bounce2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  -webkit-animation: sk-bounce 2.0s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-bounce 2.0s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.double-bounce2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-bounce {
  0%, 100% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.0) }
  50% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) }
}

@keyframes sk-bounce {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: scale(0.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.0);
  } 50% {
      transform: scale(1.0);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    }
}
```

**How to use:**
Use above component in other component(which uses async task) as shown below

**sample-view.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import {SpinnerComponent} from './spinner.component';  
import {ApiService} from './apiService';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-sample-view',
    directives: [SpinnerComponent],
    template: '<my-spinner [isRunning]="isRequesting"></my-spinner>',
})
export class SampleViewComponent {  
    public isRequesting: boolean;
    public items: Array<any>;

    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
        this.refresh();
    }

    public refresh(): void {
        this.isRequesting = true;
        this.apiService.sampleHttpGetRequest()
            .subscribe(
                result => this.items = result, 
                () => this.stopRefreshing(),
                () => this.stopRefreshing());
    }

    private stopRefreshing() {
        this.isRequesting = false;
    }
}
```

Thanks to  https://manuel-rauber.com/2016/01/05/angular-2-spinner-component/

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the previous answer, and updating for Angular 2 RC1.

blockUi.ts (note you need some soft of spinner.gif)

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'blockUi',
    template:
    `<div class="in modal-backdrop block-ui-overlay"></div>
     <div class="block-ui-message-container" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="block-ui-message">
            <table>
                <tr><td class='center space'>{{ message }}</td></tr>
                <tr><td class='center'><img src="/styles/img/spinner.gif" /></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>        
    </div>`,
    styles: [`
.block-ui-overlay {
  background-color: white;
  cursor: wait;
}
.block-ui-message-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10001;
  cursor: wait;
}
.block-ui-message {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
.space {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}`]
})
export class BlockUi {
    message: string = 'Please wait...';
}
```

blockUiService.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject, DynamicComponentLoader, ApplicationRef, ViewContainerRef, ComponentRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BlockUi } from '../components/blockUi';    

@Injectable()
export class BlockUiService {

    blockUi: ComponentRef<BlockUi>;

    constructor(
        @Inject(DynamicComponentLoader) private dynamicComponentLoader: DynamicComponentLoader,
        @Inject(ApplicationRef) private applicationRef: ApplicationRef) { }

    start(message?: string) {

        const viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef = this.applicationRef['_rootComponents'][0]._hostElement.component.viewContainerRef;

        return this.startInside(viewContainerRef, message);
    }

    startInside(viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, message?: string) {

        const blockUiRef = this.dynamicComponentLoader.loadNextToLocation(BlockUi, viewContainerRef);

        blockUiRef.then((compRef: ComponentRef<BlockUi>) => {
            this.blockUi = compRef;
            if (message !== undefined && message !== null && message.length > 0 ) {
                const blockUiInstance: BlockUi = compRef.instance;
                blockUiInstance.message = message;
            }
        });
    }

    stop() {
        if (this.blockUi) {
            this.blockUi.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
constructor(
    @Inject(BlockUiService) private blockUiService: BlockUiService
) {}

this.blockUiService.start("Saving Data...");

...

this.blockUiService.stop();
```

Comment: this.applicationRef['_rootComponents'][0]._hostElement.component.viewContainerRef -> viewContainerRef is undefined? (using Angular 2 RC2)